# How does this Python code for printing out a multiplication table work? How do I program an addition table in Python?

Tags: python, function, ansi-escape

Expected output: no return value, prints out addition and multiplication tables for values 1 to 10

I am very new to Python and really struggling with this one. I have the multiplication table finished, but was helped by a tutor. I'd like an explanation on how this code works or a simplified version of it. I'm stuck on where to start for the addition table. Specifically, I'd like to know how to format the output as a table.

```py
def mathTables():
    for i in range(1, 10+1):
     for j in range(i, (i*10)+1):
          if (j % i == 0):
              print(j, end="\t")
     print()
```

Comment: If you have a complete multiplication table code, why not use it for the addition table, simply replacing `*` with `+` ?

Comment: @Swifty because the modulo operator doesn't work for an addition table.

Comment: Oh yes, I hadn't seen the way the mult table was coded (which doesn;t seem the simplest./more obvious way to do that!).

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer: Code Explanation

The code formats the table using an escape code `\t` and a newline. `\t` is an [ansi-escape](/questions/tagged/ansi-escape) sequence that automatically inserts a [tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tab_character&useskin=vector-2022), which tabulates the next character to the next tab stop. In simpler terms, it adds spaces until the next character is at a predefined point. The newline is accomplished with a simple `print()` statement.

In the rest of the program, we have two loops and an if statement. The first loop will execute 10 times and generates the row number that goes from 1 to 10, inclusive. The second loop generates a variable `j` that goes from `i`, the row number, to the end of the scope of the row. Since our range is 1~10, the highest number for each row would be the row number times 10. The if statement will execute every time `j` is a multiple of the row number.